# RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type

Tags: image-uploading, wildfly-10

I am trying to upload a file but wildfly is throwing the following error

class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart of content type: multipart/form-data

```
12:34:04,212 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-4) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart of content type: multipart/form-data
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:34)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:151)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
  at com.company.ws.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:41)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
  at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
  at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
  at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
  at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
  at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

// Backend Code

```
@POST
  @Path("user/nlogo")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response addLogo(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @PathParam("userId") long userId, FormDataMultiPart logo) {
}
```

// App Configuration

```
@ApplicationPath("app")
public class TestWebApplication extends Application
{
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
  {
  Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(0);
  classes.add(MobileAppResource.class);
  classes.add(WebAppResource.class);
  classes.add(AdminAppResource.class);
  return super.getClasses();
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getProperties()
  {
  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>(0);
  props.put("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", "org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
  return props;
  }
}
```

Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this post for the above issue: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/

They have provided solution for file uploading.

Comment: No it is not a jersey example, it is a resteasy example